# Multi-Site Craft 3 - How to set defaultTokenDuration to shorter duration for just 1 of the sites?

Tags: users, session

I currently have a multi-site Craft 3 install with this in the general.php config file (amongst other settings)

```
return [
   '*' => [
       'defaultTokenDuration' => 259200, //72 hours
    ]
]
```

Which works fine for all sites allowing logged in users to remain logged in for 72 hours. I'm adding a new site where we need the duration to be 30 minutes.

I tried this:

```
return [
   '*' => [
        'defaultTokenDuration' => [
            '*' => 259200, //72 hours
            'otherSite' => 1800 //30 minutes
        ]
    ]
]
```

where 'otherSite' is the handle of the new site. Craft is throwing this error:

`yii\base\InvalidConfigException: Unable to convert to seconds. in /Users/chad/Repos/gcx-craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/ConfigHelper.php:49`

I also tried replacing the * with the handle of the primary site and saw the same error, so I assume listing all sites with a value in that array is useless. Is there any way to specify different values for different sites for this setting?

Answer (score 0):

**This is completely inaccurate, please disregard!** I’ll work with Chad to come up with something useful, or delete it outright.

---

Multi-environment [configuration](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html) (3.x) uses site handles at the top level of the returned array.

Currently, Craft interprets this as having the following `defaultTokenDuration` for all sites…

```php
[
  '*' => 259200,
  'otherSite' => 1800,
]
```

…which isn't a valid "duration" format!

Instead, your config file should look something like this:

```php
return [
   '*' => [
        'defaultTokenDuration' => 259200,
    ],
    'otherSite' => [
        'defaultTokenDuration' => 1800,
    ],
];
```

**Keep in mind:** These tokens aren’t always generated in circumstances where the current "site" is known or defined—for example, an administrator sending a password reset email to a user, or a live preview request.

Comment: Thank you - but my config array at the top level is environment-specific, not site specific. Can you explain how I'd add the otherSite array to this? https://gist.github.com/chadcrowell/d5fce78742c0185fd3c32b509613aeba